# Proving the completeness of $L(V,W)$ when $W$ is complete.

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V,{\Vert \cdot \Vert)_V})$ and $(W,{\Vert \cdot \Vert_W})$ be two normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $L(V,W)$ the set of all continous linear operators from $V$ to $W$. Assuming that $W$ with the induced metric is complete, I want to show that $L(V,W)$ with the usual operator norm (supremum definition) is complete.

So I have to show that every Cauchy sequence in $L(V,W)$ converges in $L(V,W)$. My approach is to consider a Cauchy sequence in $L(V,W)$ and then for each $x \in V$ construct a corresponding sequence in $W$ and show that this sequence is Cauchy. My problem is that I am stuck on proving that this constructed sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the property of the operator norm that $\|T(x)\| \leq \|T\|_{op} \|x\|$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. Now I can use this inequality together with the supremum definition of the operator norm to prove the cauchy property.